# Dynamic component not getting rendered

Tags: angular

I have created dynamic component but it not getting rendered. but the thing is i am able to show the markup in developer tool.

here is my code.

```
       var rect = this.svg.selectAll(".button");

      var newRects = rect.enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + (d.x + 460) + "," + d.y + ")";
      })
        newRects.append("g")
        .each((d: Data, i) => {
            const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componenttoload);
            var component = factory.create(this.viewContainerRef.parentInjector);
            component.instance.data = d;
            component.instance.width = this.rectGrid.nodeSize()[0];
            component.instance.height = this.rectGrid.nodeSize()[1];
            this.appRef.attachView(component.hostView);
            component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            const componentRoot: HTMLElement = (component.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0];
            const node = newRects[0][i]; 
            this.render.appendChild(node, componentRoot);
        })
```

Comment: Can you replicate this on a Sample StackBlitz?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question, maybe add generic class and have a try.

```
export interface Custom {data:any}  

<Custom>componentRef.instance).data= 'data';
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Compelete working example you can find in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exc9j9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You need `document.body.appendChild()`

```
appendDialogComponentToBody() {
   const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DialogComponent);
   const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
   this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
   const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
   document.body.appendChild(domElem);

   this.dialogComponentRef = componentRef;
}
```

Comment: i have tried this and its working. but i dont want to append the view to the body. if you notice my code you will see the newRects[0][i] this is the list of elements i want to create the view/component in each element

Comment: exactly what are you trying to do? can you explain as per my given solution?

Comment: ok. i have updated my code. if u see there i am dynamicaaly creating 'g' in svg and i want to show the component view in each 'g'